# How do I reflect a list of EntityObjects?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, reflection, entity-framework-4

I've looked all over the net and can't seem to find a decent solution.  I'm a noob regarding Entity Framework. What I've been able to work with I really like. In past projects, I've been able to pull a Dictionary of objects that I can use later like this:

```
Dictionary<string, MyBaseType> myTypes = new Dictionary<string, MyBaseType>();
var types = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
                                           .Where(t => t.BaseType != null && t.BaseType.Name.Equals("MyBaseType")).ToArray();
object ct;
foreach (Type c in types)
{
    ct = Activator.CreateInstance(c);
    myTypes.Add(ct.GetType().Name, ct as MyBaseType);
}

var myob = myTypes["SomeName"];
myob.DoFoo(); // this is a method of my basetype class or my interface
```

I need to do something similar for an MVC w/ EF4 project. I tried using EntityObject as the base type, but for whatever reason, the Executing Assembly won't reflect them.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check:

1. What is the base class for your EF objects - mine derive directly from System.Object for example.
2. That you are looking for them in the right assembly - are they declared in the assembly that executes the code from your sample?

Comment: I'm not using anything special. Just an EDMX in my main project. I can see each entity is base type of EntityObject. I thought I could just reflect from there and go on, but as I said, the ExecutingAssembly doesn't recognize those types. If the types generated in a main project EDMX aren't in the Executing Assembly, where are they?

Comment: The question is 'what is your executing assembly'? Look at 2. Where is your sample code declared? Is it in the same assembly as your EDMX? Also, what is the visibility of your EF objects? Are they public?